# Received my lent money which the debtor acquired from haram source. Is it halal for me?

Tags: halal-haram, money, gambling, debt

Some years ago, I've lent some money to my cousin who was in need. He had trouble paying me back for a long time until last week after I knew he got a lot of money enough to pay me back in full. But yesterday I've been told that he won the money from gambling and exactly he paid me all his debt with that money. Is the money `halal` for me or is it `haram` only because I know it's came from `haram` way ? If it is, then should I give him back the money, or donate it to somewhere, or just throw it all away ?

Comment: According to this [fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/13503/taking-from-one-who-deals-in-haraam-things), it is permissible for you since you acquired it in permissible manner